# Do SQL Server differential backups require transaction logging on?

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

I'm having trouble finding an answer on Google searches: Can I create differential backups on ANY SQL Server DB, no matter the settings (such as transaction logging on or off, etc)?

Comment: Don't move the goal posts after you have an answer when you invaliate existing answers. I have rolled your edit back.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation, [Differential Backups (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/differential-backups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15), answers this in the very first line:

> This backup and restore topic is relevant for **all** SQL Server databases.

Emphasis on *all* is mine.

Comment: Okay, thank you. One more question: what we want is to have a separate DB serve certain types of requests without having to do full restores. If we do a full backup and restore once on the weekends and then create differential backups every hour, can those differential backups be applied to the existing DB which has no changes since last restore faster and with less disruption? Like, can you apply the differential backup only to an existing DB?

Comment: These are all completely different questions, @TamerRifai , and should be asked as new questions